# A 100µF capacitor and a 15kΩ resistor are placed in series with a 9V battery

Tags: voltage, homework

How long will it take the capacitor to charge to about 63% of the battery’s voltage when first connected?

Comment: This is an example of a homework style question. What have you tried? Have you attempted to solve it, and if so, what did you get? You must show some work/effort  and explain what you did or did not understand. This site is not a homework-answering service. Edit your question to show what you've attempted and explain where you are stuck. We are happy to help in that case.

Comment: Hint: 'about 63%' means one time constant for an exponential rise/fall.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a homework question without any demonstrated effort.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please note that it's not a free design house, homework-answering service or on-line technical encyclopedia, copied out to you on demand. People will help you take the next step if your question shows you've done as much as you possibly could on your own - which yours doesn't, I'm afraid. Please edit your question and greatly improve it. Show your work and findings so far in considerable detail with any schematic. The schematic tool here is easy to use. The better the quality of question, the better the quality of the answers you will attract. Again, a very warm welcome.

Answer (score 1):

- C = .1E-3 F
- R = 15E3 Ω

τ = RC

(RC time constant)

[image]

https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/rc/rc_1.html

I don't want to do all the work for this homework style question. Instead, here's an idea:

1. Find τ.